# Q: How to speed up ido when opening a file in /etc?

Tags: ido-find-file

Emacs 24.5.1, Funtoo.

When I'd like to open a file in /etc, the ido-find-file would stuck for about two minutes. It looks ido is going thru the / dir for caching the directory names, but this is really annoying. This only happens for the first time after Emacs started. Are there a switch that can speed this up?